# Internal Server Error [ flask on apache with ubuntu ]

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu

I am a student who started studying web development.
I want to make a web page created with flask. and that is accessible from the outside.

So, I use flask on apache.

I have done various examples on the internet.

Also, my apache is on. sh.com succeeded when i connected

but, sh.com:5246 was an error [ internal server error ]

I attach my error log. please give solution

Thank you

[flask 1.0.2 / ubuntu 16.04 / apache 2.4.17 ]

`shs.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask setting up \n\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`shs.wsgi`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/flask')
from shs import app as application
```

`000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:5246>
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin jk5466@sh.com
ServerName www.sh.com
ServerAlias sh.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog /var/www/flask/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/flask/logs/access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess flask user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
WSGIProcessGroup flask
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/shs.wsgi
Alias /static/ /var/www/flask/static/

<Directory /var/www/flask/static/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

`port.conf`

```
Listen 80
Listen 5246
Listen 8000
Listen 5000
```

"error.log" when i commanded 'service apache2 restart'

```
[Tue Apr 02 11:41:31.167998 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10615:tid 140678171088768] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Apr 02 11:41:32.266356 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 11059:tid 139930407794560] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Tue Apr 02 11:41:32.266394 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 11059:tid 139930407794560] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Tue Apr 02 11:41:32.267048 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11059:tid 139930407794560] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 02 11:41:32.267072 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11059:tid 139930407794560] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: have you created virtual environment for this?

Comment: What's in the error log after you have triggered this error?